# Elliptic Curve with Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) implementation on BouncyCastle

Tags: cryptography, java

I am creating the same question that I created in Stackoverflow, because it seems this site is a better place to ask.

I am trying to implement ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) but I couldn't find any example in Java which uses Bouncy Castle. So, now, I created the keys, but I really don't know what kind of functions should I have to use to create a signature and verify it.

```
public static KeyPair GenerateKeys() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                            NoSuchProviderException,
                                            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
    ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("B-571");
    KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
    return g.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Thank you!